# Disable Editable property UITextField

Tags: iphone, combobox, uitextfield

I have a problem disabling editing of a `UITextField`. I'm trying to use my text field as a combobox but when I use my combobox style, my text is editable. When I set `userInteractionEnabled = NO` to prevent editing, I can't see my text field as a combobox.  What can I do for this problem?

Comment: Do you need to open your combo when the user taps on the text field?

Comment: Yes .When user taps on the texfield i want to see my combobox values/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You display an action sheet on textfieldediting.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([textField isEqual:myTextField]){
       UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please select an option" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Option1", @"Option2", @"Option3", nil];
       [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
       return NO; 
    } 
    return YES;
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

[myTextField setText:[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
txtBox.editable = NO;
```

rather than,

```
txtBox.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: When I have used these,I cant see my textfield as a combobox..?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that using uitextfield as combobox is a good solution.The problem is is you disable the userinteraction or make your textview uneditable how would you catch user taps and activate the list?

If i were you i would refer to a button an a small tableview that pops up whe nyou click the button.It is not easy to implement but a more elegant solution.

Comment: But I have prepared everything ,so I think it will be better to disable Textfield if we have one solution of course..

Comment: what you eman wit hi have prepared everything? how do you plan to show the list when user taps on a textfield

Comment: What i do not get is if you are not using fundemental functionality of UITextField why aren"t you using buttons instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use this UITextField delegate:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Set return NO and open your Combobox.

Comment: - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
        return NO;
    [self showPicker:textField];

}
 when Im doing this I cant see combobox?

Comment: if you disable the user interaction for textfield this will never called

Comment: make sure you have set delegate of TextField and your method showPicker is working correct.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting buttons or something on top of your UITextFields. Setting Textfields editable to NO is not a good idea, but, simply tricking your UI.